# Replacing in Javascript " with '

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string and it needs to be passed on as a JSON, but then, inside the string, I cannot have " signs, so I was thinking about replacing them with ' signs in my Javascript.

I tried this:

```
var myString = myString.replace("\"", "\'");
```

But unfortunately, it only replaced the first occurrence of " in my string. Help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You should use a regex to solve the problem.

Hope it helps you.

```js
var myString = 'this "is" a test'
myString = myString.replace(/\"/g, "'");
console.log(myString)
```

Answer (score 0):

use the regular expression, with the flag g to replace

```
var myString = myString.replace(/\"/g, '\'');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here split the string with `"` and join the string with `'`.

```js
var data = '[{"endDate":"2017-04-22","req":"2017-04-19","nr":2,"type":"CO","startDate":"2017-04-20","Dep":"2017-04-19"},{"endDate":"2017-04-22","req":"2017-04-20","nr":3,"type":"CM","startDate":"2017-04-20","Dep":"2017-04-19"}]';
var result=data.split('"').join("'");
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the global flag /g. Try this:

```
var myString=myString.replace(/"/g,"\'");
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var s = 'This " is " Just " for test'.replace(/\"/g, "'");
console.log(s);
```